# I'm trying out MagicalRecord but why does data being erased only after adding a new attribute?

Tags: ios, core-data

Data was gone after adding only a new attribute,  I already have this on my AppDelegate init method
[MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Add these two methods in your `AppDelegate.m:`

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveOnlySelfAndWait];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [MagicalRecord cleanUp];
}
```

Comment: @BaloniBoi If you're on the simulator, make sure you don't just abruptly stop the app via the Xcode stop button. First, go into your homescreen, then you can halt the app.

Comment: I'm actually running it on the device.

Answer (score 0):

check out this [How do I set up Core Data lightweight migration using MagicalRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841158/how-do-i-set-up-core-data-lightweight-migration-using-magicalrecord/32259290#32259290)

Make sure you versioned your data model correctly.